# Laravel 5.3 save biginteger

Tags: php, laravel, pdo, model, save

Sometimes we need to save big integer in DB from Model. PDO can't do that well. Because PDO convert our attributes.

So you need to declare attributes as string in your Model. But it does not work :)

And I found one way when it work! (thanks xdebug):

```
protected $casts = [
  "category_id" => "json",
  "product_id" => "json",
];
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge. If I understand right how this site works you should create a real question, then respond to yourself and accept your answer. Thanks for helping BTW! You can also post on the documentation topic

Comment: @Eugene Panov.Thanks for sharing knowledge.Even this is new concept for me.can you add more detaIl so it will help everybody to undestand very well

Comment: We appreciate users sharing their own knowledge, but please split your post into a problem statement (question), and solution (answer). For more info, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer.